# How to calculate DATE Difference in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, datediff

Here I need to calculate the difference of the two dates in the `PostgreSQL`.

**In SQL Server**: Like we do in `SQL Server` its much easier.

```
DATEDIFF(Day, MIN(joindate), MAX(joindate)) AS DateDifference;
```

**My Try**: I am trying using the following script:

```
(Max(joindate) - Min(joindate)) as DateDifference;
```

**Question**:

- Is my method correct?
- Is there any function in `PostgreSQL` to calculate this?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Your calculation is correct for `DATE` types, but if your values are timestamps, you should probably use [`EXTRACT`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT)  (or DATE_PART) to be sure to get only the difference in *full* days;

```
EXTRACT(DAY FROM MAX(joindate)-MIN(joindate)) AS DateDifference
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/0d359/2). Note the timestamp difference being 1 second less than 2 full days.

Comment: @JurajPetrik Hm, `SELECT EXTRACT(DAY FROM TO_TIMESTAMP('2016-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')-TO_TIMESTAMP('2015-03-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD'));` gives 306 days which would seem to be correct (and greater than 31).

Answer (score 22):

a simple way would be to cast the dates into timestamps and take their difference and then extract the DAY part.

if you want real difference

```
select extract(day from 'DATE_A'::timestamp - 'DATE_B'::timestamp);
```

if you want absolute difference

```
select abs(extract(day from 'DATE_A'::timestamp - 'DATE_B'::timestamp));
```

Comment: The question is old, so maybe it didn't work back then, but now you can do `select date_x - date_y as thing`

Comment: One warning here. This only extracts the day component from the period. A) 3 days 23 hours would still result in 3, B) `extract(hour from ...)` 3 days and 23 hours will result in 23 and not 95 and C) the month and year component is always 0.

Answer (score 18):

CAST both fields to datatype DATE and you can use a minus:

```
(CAST(MAX(joindate) AS date) - CAST(MIN(joindate) AS date)) as DateDifference
```

Test case:

```
SELECT  (CAST(MAX(joindate) AS date) - CAST(MIN(joindate) AS date)) as DateDifference
FROM 
    generate_series('2014-01-01'::timestamp, '2014-02-01'::timestamp, interval '1 hour') g(joindate);
```

Result: 31

Or create a function datediff():

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION datediff(timestamp, timestamp) 
RETURNS int 
LANGUAGE sql 
AS
$$
    SELECT CAST($1 AS date) - CAST($2 AS date) as DateDifference
$$;
```

Comment: After creating function. I just need to use `datediff(joindate,joindate)` right?

Comment: inside an sql query, it wont work by itself (just adding this for future readers)

Answer (score 14):

This is how I usually do it. A simple number of days perspective of B minus A.

```
DATE_PART('day', MAX(joindate) - MIN(joindate)) as date_diff
```

Comment: I think this can generate negative dates if the two dates are not from the same month.

Answer (score 8):

This is not a direct answer to OP's question, however, this is the answer I was looking for when my search brought me to this thread.

For someone who wants to create a human-readable string that denotes the difference between two dates, consider using AGE().

```
 AGE(table.end_date, table.start_date)
```

It produces results that looks like these:

```
0:00:27

3 days 22:06:39.833264
4 days 01:12:39.473559
20 days 17:53:20.23287
23 days 21:01:15.150703

1 mon 19 days 01:52:24.262275
2 mons 17 days 05:04:12.277099
2 mons 17 days 04:59:21.618069
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a timestamp already you will need not to cast anything,

For the absolute difference @zubair-0 answer is great here is implementation an using...

```
select abs(extract(day from A - B)) from table_name;
```

**Note:
A and B are timestamps as data types**